# Quarkus Graalvm Apache POI - error undefined reference to `Java_sun_font"

Tags: apache-poi, awt, native, quarkus, graalvm

I have a simple project with Quarkus 2.3.0 and Apache POI, I used the org.apache.poi.xssf.streaming.SXSSFWorkbook class that makes use of AWT fonts. When generating the native image, the following error occurred during execution: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: sun.awt.X11FontManager.
After included in the "reflection-config.json" file the Apache POI entries plus the two below:

```
{
  "name":"sun.awt.X11FontManager",
  "methods":[{"name":"<init>","parameterTypes":[] }]
},
{
  "name":"sun.awt.X11GraphicsEnvironment",
  "methods":[{"name":"<init>","parameterTypes":[] }]
}
```

When generating the native project again, the error occurred:

```
[code-with-quarkus-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT-runner:26]      compile:  55.103,37 ms,  3,99 GB
[code-with-quarkus-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT-runner:26]        image:   5.921,10 ms,  3,99 GB
[code-with-quarkus-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT-runner:26]        write:   2.661,82 ms,  3,99 GB
Fatal error:java.lang.RuntimeException: There was an error linking the native image: Linker command exited with 1
Linker command executed:
/usr/bin/gcc -z noexecstack -Wl,--gc-sections -Wl,--dynamic-list -Wl,/tmp/SVM-1689872881100263417/exported_symbols.list -Wl,--exclude-libs,ALL -Wl,-x -o /project/code-with-quarkus-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT-runner code-with-quarkus-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT-runner.o /opt/graalvm/lib/svm/clibraries/linux-amd64/liblibchelper.a /opt/graalvm/lib/static/linux-amd64/glibc/libawt_headless.a /opt/graalvm/lib/static/linux-amd64/glibc/libawt.a /opt/graalvm/lib/static/linux-amd64/glibc/libnet.a /opt/graalvm/lib/static/linux-amd64/glibc/libextnet.a /opt/graalvm/lib/static/linux-amd64/glibc/libnio.a /opt/graalvm/lib/static/linux-amd64/glibc/libjava.a /opt/graalvm/lib/static/linux-amd64/glibc/libfdlibm.a /opt/graalvm/lib/static/linux-amd64/glibc/libsunec.a /opt/graalvm/lib/static/linux-amd64/glibc/libzip.a /opt/graalvm/lib/svm/clibraries/linux-amd64/libjvm.a -v -L/tmp/SVM-1689872881100263417 -L/opt/graalvm/lib/static/linux-amd64/glibc -L/opt/graalvm/lib/svm/clibraries/linux-amd64 -lstdc++ -lm -lstdc++ -lz -lpthread -ldl -lrt
Linker command output:
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=/usr/bin/gcc
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/usr/libexec/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/8/lto-wrapper
OFFLOAD_TARGET_NAMES=nvptx-none
OFFLOAD_TARGET_DEFAULT=1
Target: x86_64-redhat-linux
Configured with: ../configure --enable-bootstrap --enable-languages=c,c++,fortran,lto --prefix=/usr --mandir=/usr/share/man --infodir=/usr/share/info --with-bugurl=http://bugzilla.redhat.com/bugzilla --enable-shared --enable-threads=posix --enable-checking=release --enable-multilib --with-system-zlib --enable-__cxa_atexit --disable-libunwind-exceptions --enable-gnu-unique-object --enable-linker-build-id --with-gcc-major-version-only --with-linker-hash-style=gnu --enable-plugin --enable-initfini-array --with-isl --disable-libmpx --enable-offload-targets=nvptx-none --without-cuda-driver --enable-gnu-indirect-function --enable-cet --with-tune=generic --with-arch_32=x86-64 --build=x86_64-redhat-linux
Thread model: posix
gcc version 8.4.1 20200928 (Red Hat 8.4.1-1) (GCC)
COMPILER_PATH=/usr/libexec/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/8/:/usr/libexec/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/8/:/usr/libexec/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/:/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/8/:/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/
LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/8/:/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/8/../../../../lib64/:/lib/../lib64/:/usr/lib/../lib64/:/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/8/../../../:/lib/:/usr/lib/
COLLECT_GCC_OPTIONS='-z' 'noexecstack' '-o' '/project/code-with-quarkus-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT-runner' '-v' '-L/tmp/SVM-1689872881100263417' '-L/opt/graalvm/lib/static/linux-amd64/glibc' '-L/opt/graalvm/lib/svm/clibraries/linux-amd64' '-mtune=generic' '-march=x86-64'
 /usr/libexec/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/8/collect2 -plugin /usr/libexec/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/8/liblto_plugin.so -plugin-opt=/usr/libexec/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/8/lto-wrapper -plugin-opt=-fresolution=/tmp/ccvYfyBM.res -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lgcc -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lgcc_s -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lc -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lgcc -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lgcc_s --build-id --no-add-needed --eh-frame-hdr --hash-style=gnu -m elf_x86_64 -dynamic-linker /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 -o /project/code-with-quarkus-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT-runner -z noexecstack /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/8/../../../../lib64/crt1.o /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/8/../../../../lib64/crti.o /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/8/crtbegin.o -L/tmp/SVM-1689872881100263417 -L/opt/graalvm/lib/static/linux-amd64/glibc -L/opt/graalvm/lib/svm/clibraries/linux-amd64 -L/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/8 -L/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/8/../../../../lib64 -L/lib/../lib64 -L/usr/lib/../lib64 -L/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/8/../../.. --gc-sections --dynamic-list /tmp/SVM-1689872881100263417/exported_symbols.list --exclude-libs ALL -x code-with-quarkus-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT-runner.o /opt/graalvm/lib/svm/clibraries/linux-amd64/liblibchelper.a /opt/graalvm/lib/static/linux-amd64/glibc/libawt_headless.a /opt/graalvm/lib/static/linux-amd64/glibc/libawt.a /opt/graalvm/lib/static/linux-amd64/glibc/libnet.a /opt/graalvm/lib/static/linux-amd64/glibc/libextnet.a /opt/graalvm/lib/static/linux-amd64/glibc/libnio.a /opt/graalvm/lib/static/linux-amd64/glibc/libjava.a /opt/graalvm/lib/static/linux-amd64/glibc/libfdlibm.a /opt/graalvm/lib/static/linux-amd64/glibc/libsunec.a /opt/graalvm/lib/static/linux-amd64/glibc/libzip.a /opt/graalvm/lib/svm/clibraries/linux-amd64/libjvm.a -lstdc++ -lm -lstdc++ -lz -lpthread -ldl -lrt -lgcc --as-needed -lgcc_s --no-as-needed -lc -lgcc --as-needed -lgcc_s --no-as-needed /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/8/crtend.o /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/8/../../../../lib64/crtn.o
code-with-quarkus-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT-runner.o:(.data+0xf0): undefined reference to `Java_sun_font_NullFontScaler_getGlyphImage'
code-with-quarkus-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT-runner.o:(.data+0x138): undefined reference to `Java_sun_font_FreetypeFontScaler_getFontMetricsNative'
code-with-quarkus-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT-runner.o:(.data+0x280): undefined reference to `Java_sun_font_NativeStrike_createNullScalerContext'
code-with-quarkus-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT-runner.o:(.data+0x290): undefined reference to `Java_sun_font_NativeFont_getFontMetrics'
code-with-quarkus-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT-runner.o:(.data+0x2a0): undefined reference to `Java_sun_font_FreetypeFontScaler_getGlyphAdvanceNative'
code-with-quarkus-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT-runner.o:(.data+0x2d8): undefined reference to `Java_sun_font_SunLayoutEngine_shape'
code-with-quarkus-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT-runner.o:(.data+0x350): undefined reference to `Java_sun_font_FreetypeFontScaler_getGlyphMetricsNative'
code-with-quarkus-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT-runner.o:(.data+0x4a0): undefined reference to `Java_sun_font_FreetypeFontScaler_getMissingGlyphCodeNative'
code-with-quarkus-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT-runner.o:(.data+0x610): undefined reference to `Java_sun_font_FreetypeFontScaler_getNumGlyphsNative'
code-with-quarkus-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT-runner.o:(.data+0x668): undefined reference to `Java_sun_font_FreetypeFontScaler_createScalerContextNative'
code-with-quarkus-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT-runner.o:(.data+0x808): undefined reference to `Java_sun_font_StrikeCache_freeIntPointer'
code-with-quarkus-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT-runner.o:(.data+0x830): undefined reference to `Java_sun_font_FreetypeFontScaler_getGlyphOutlineBoundsNative'
code-with-quarkus-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT-runner.o:(.data+0x848): undefined reference to `Java_sun_font_FreetypeFontScaler_getGlyphCodeNative'
code-with-quarkus-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT-runner.o:(.data+0x910): undefined reference to `Java_sun_font_NullFontScaler_getNullScalerContext'
code-with-quarkus-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT-runner.o:(.data+0xaa8): undefined reference to `Java_sun_font_NativeFont_getGlyphAdvance'
code-with-quarkus-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT-runner.o:(.data+0xb48): undefined reference to `Java_sun_font_StrikeCache_freeLongPointer'
code-with-quarkus-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT-runner.o:(.data+0xc48): undefined reference to `Java_sun_font_NativeFont_countGlyphs'
code-with-quarkus-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT-runner.o:(.data+0xc90): undefined reference to `Java_sun_font_FreetypeFontScaler_disposeNativeScaler'
code-with-quarkus-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT-runner.o:(.data+0xcd0): undefined reference to `Java_sun_font_SunLayoutEngine_createFace'
code-with-quarkus-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT-runner.o:(.data+0xd58): undefined reference to `Java_sun_font_NativeStrike_createScalerContext'
code-with-quarkus-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT-runner.o:(.data+0xeb8): undefined reference to `Java_sun_font_FreetypeFontScaler_getGlyphImageNative'
code-with-quarkus-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT-runner.o:(.data+0xf60): undefined reference to `Java_sun_font_FreetypeFontScaler_initNativeScaler'
code-with-quarkus-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT-runner.o:(.data+0xfa8): undefined reference to `Java_sun_font_FreetypeFontScaler_getGlyphOutlineNative'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
    at com.oracle.svm.hosted.image.NativeImageViaCC.handleLinkerFailure(NativeImageViaCC.java:499)
    at com.oracle.svm.hosted.image.NativeImageViaCC.write(NativeImageViaCC.java:446)
    at com.oracle.svm.hosted.NativeImageGenerator.doRun(NativeImageGenerator.java:660)
    at com.oracle.svm.hosted.NativeImageGenerator.run(NativeImageGenerator.java:491)
    at com.oracle.svm.hosted.NativeImageGeneratorRunner.buildImage(NativeImageGeneratorRunner.java:380)
    at com.oracle.svm.hosted.NativeImageGeneratorRunner.build(NativeImageGeneratorRunner.java:543)
    at com.oracle.svm.hosted.NativeImageGeneratorRunner.main(NativeImageGeneratorRunner.java:119)
    at com.oracle.svm.hosted.NativeImageGeneratorRunner$JDK9Plus.main(NativeImageGeneratorRunner.java:573)
[code-with-quarkus-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT-runner:26]      [total]: 139.407,09 ms,  3,99 GB

Printing build artifacts to: /project/code-with-quarkus-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT-runner.build_artifacts.txt
Error: Image build request failed with exit status 1
```

Project on https://github.com/guilhermemunizsantos/excel-quarkus

Error occurer when execute:

```
%M2_HOME%\bin\mvn package -Pnative -Dquarkus.native.container-build=true
```

Any help?

Comment: Hi, any solution to your problem? I've the same error. Thx